# dynamically making textarea ckeditor

Tags: textarea, ckeditor, undefined

When i try to make these dynamically made textareas into CEditor fields i get the error: 
TypeError: b is undefined

my code:

```
    var input = $("<textarea>").addClass("textAreaClassTest");
    //input.setAttribute("id", "como");
    //input.setIdAttribute("id", "como");
    //input.ID = 'como';
    CKEDITOR.replace('como');
    item.append(input);
    //CKEDITOR.replace('como');

    return item;
```

i cant  seem to give the textarea an id - any id's :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using jQuery and only working with 1 or more text areas at a time. So you can get the text areas and assign them ids and use them as below.

```
//select all text areas
var input = $("textarea");
var list = new Array();
var count = 0;

input.each(function () {
    count++;
    $this = $(this);
    $this.attr("id", "como" + count);
    console.log('id is "' + $this.attr("id") + '" and text is "' + $this.text() + '"');
    CKEDITOR.replace($this.attr("id"));
    list.push($this.attr("id"));
});
//return the list of replaced text area ids
return list;
```

Comment: You don't have to assign them ids. You can pass elements to the `CKEDITOR.replace` function.

Comment: Thanks Reinmar, won't need the ids just to do the CKEDITOR.replace. From the question it seemed like the user wanted to assign them ids and return the textarea objects maybe user had something else in mind.

Comment: i have window where  the user can place multiple text areas - when these text areas are placed or focused i would  like to  turn  them into ckeditor fields - when they  are  unfocused  i would  like  to change  them  back  into normal textareas - or  maybe  just  hide  the editing  menu ckeditor  supplies

Comment: but  i still cant  even  get the  newly placed textareas to turn into ckeditors

Comment: can you explain what part of code is not working or paste some example of what you're doing?

Comment: the replace-function did not get the needed parameter - it seems the textarea was not loaded onto the page at the timei tried to replace it - if i put the replace-code in a click(or focus)-function on the textarea it changes - now  i just have to figure out how to autofocus it when it has loaded

Comment: I think you need to wait for the CKEDITOR to fire InstanceReady before you replace the textareas so try something like `CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(e) { // place your replace code in here});`